# "ng-class" on each clicked item

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need to add a class on selected `<li>` like I have shown in demo but dont want it to be removed if I click on another `<li>`.

Please help

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <ul ng-controller="myCtrl">
        <li ng-repeat="item in model.items" class="commonClass" ng-class="{'on': model.selected==item}" ng-click="model.selected=item">{{ item.name }}</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

JS

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('myCtrl', function ($scope) {

    $scope.model = {
        selected: null,
        items : [
            {name: "Apple"}, 
            {name: "Banana"}, 
            {name: "California"}
         ]
    };
})
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/JfeLz/1/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add like this

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <ul ng-controller="myCtrl">
        <li ng-repeat="item in model.items" class="commonClass" ng-class="{'on': selected==$index}" ng-click="selected=$index">{{ item.name }}</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```